# Ubuntu 14.10 does not install in virtualbox

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, resolution, 14.10

I'm currently running Windows 8.1 x64 (a problem in itself that I can't change sadly ;-P) with the latest version of VirtualBox (4.3.18 r96516). I managed to get the server version up and running with no issues but I cannot get the desktop version running.

I can boot to the menu and start the process (select the option to install and/or try) and it will get through the inital Ubuntu 14.10 loading screen (with the progess "bar/dots") but then we get to a nasty screen of distorted colors and that's it.

My hypothesis is that the display driver/server isn't working with VirtualBox and what I'm essentially seeing is the display in a crappy mode (16colors@62x24) because I am able to see a perfectly fine screen with cursor working and everything and then suddenly I'm in that nasty screen. The mouse does show up (nasty looking and filling the entire screen) but nothing else.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here are my settings in an album (I can add more if desired but I put in what I thought were the most relevant):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tell us what configuration have you made for that Ubuntu vm.

Comment: Updated post to include link to settings screenshot album. Here it is again for convenience: http://imgur.com/a/JGOlL.

Comment: Give it 128 MB of video memory.

Comment: The 128 MB of memory did nothing. The solution provided by Gipnokote was the proper solution.

Comment: Bug is logged here with VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13615

Comment: ...and is now logged on Launchpad here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/1443853

Comment: Same issue with Lubuntu 16.10. Enabling EFI was the only fix that worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/852962/lubuntu-as-vbox-guest-bad-display/852967#852967

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (you will see the shell) and then <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. Depending on the Virtualbox configuration use <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> together instead of <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

You are good to proceed with the installation.

---

This works by forcing the kernel's graphics buffer / X / XRandR to re-detect the monitor and display in the proper resolution.

Comment: Alt+Ctrl+F1 is captured by the host. Using rightctrl+F1 and then rightcontrol+F7 works.

Comment: I had a similar issue like this in the past and enabling 3D Acceleration and increasing the VRAM amount allowed me to install the OS.

Comment: To work when using an OSX host, you must press `Left Cmd` + `fn` + `F1` and then `Left Cmd` + `fn` + `F7`.

Comment: For me <right_ctrl+f7> then <right_ctrl+f1> worked.  nabling 3D acceleration and increasing VRAM did not help here.

Comment: Workaround succesful with same problem in Oracle VB 5. 2.12, lubuntu 18.04 LTS. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

You need to switch between `tty` so the Guest GUI can refresh itself and detect the environment correctly. This is currently a minor bug.

I would suggest doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> but if you are like me, this would be received by the Host and not the Guest.

The correct key combination to switch to tty1 while focusing on the Guest Window is:

<kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

followed by

<kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Noticed that I am using the <kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd> which is the same one used by VirtualBox to escape focus of the VM.

Tested with:

- VirtualBox 4.3.18
- Host Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit
- Guest Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit

Another way of making it work is like Whaaaat mentions. In the VM Settings, under the System section, activate the **Enable EFI** checkbox.

[image]

But also make sure your chipset is also set to **PIIX3** since **ICH9** will not work. It will leave you in a black screen.

[image]

When EFI is enabled, the boot process might take a little bit longer and the screen might stay black until the Ubuntu logo appears when booting. If you see **Booting into secure mode** right after starting the VM then you won't have any problems, if not, then wait a bit.

[image]

[image]

Note that I tested this with 32 MB of Video, 64 MB of Video and 128 MB of video. The video has nothing to do with the problem in either 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat I am a ninja thief dude!!.. and also was testing your method which is good but if you can, add the Chipset issue with ICH9.

Comment: For OSX host newbies (like me) the required key combination is fn+ctrl+alt+f1/f7

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. After a wasted 20 minutes of failures this immediately worked, the first time. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 16):

Enable EFI mode.

[image]

When booting, you may see a few errors. However, these are harmless and do nothing to your system. It will still work.

When using EFI mode, make sure the chipset is set to PIIX3 mode, like in my picture. Having it on ICH9 is ***not*** fun. However, PIIX3 is the default, so you shouldn't have to set it.

Apparently Ubuntu and EFI now like each other, so they work together better than alone.

Comment: +1 For another great method.. will stea...borrow it.

Comment: If EFI is enabled it seems that it does the initial prompt via a console menu, hence avoiding the (GUI and) problem. Nice!

Comment: Yes, but how does one proceed from there onward? That's the question.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the chipset to ICH9, disabled nested paging. That solved it for me.

Comment: Works! Make sure you disable 3D acceleration and PAE/NX if you had enabled those.

Comment: Didn't work here, I'm sad to relate.

Answer (score 2):

I think is problem with 64 bit versions. At the same virtual machine the 64 bit doesn't work but 32 does. With 128M of video works fine the 64 bit one.

Comment: Hard to say but this doesn't address the issue. The work around was provided by Gipnokote.

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused 14.04 with 14.10 that doesn't work with 128M os video memory. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Think Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit worked like a charm with 16 MB video memory in VirtualBox and aced 'em all with 128 MB video memory. But could not compete with Linux Mint.

Comment: Unfortunately for me (64-bit windows 10 host) 32 and 64 bit ubuntu seemed to exhibit the same failure...