# 16.04 Live CD screen resolution problem?

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, 16.04, display-resolution

I'm not sure if its me, but I have some problems with the 16.04 live CDs. See for yourself (using VirtualBox):

[image: Ubuntu 16.04 starting]
[image: Ubuntu 16.04 install screen]

VirtualBox settings:
Base Memory: 3000MB
Processors: 1
Video Memory: 128MB
No 3D Acceleration enabled.

The strange thing is that I tried Kubuntu 16.04 live CD on a HP Touchsmart 14 laptop and the same thing happened. It didn't happen with Xubuntu 16.04 (same laptop). What can be the problem?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/541006/ubuntu-14-10-does-not-install-in-virtualbox

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/295222/trouble-with-ubuntu-installation-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix this press <kbd>right ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to go into TTY then you can switch back with <kbd>right ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, this sorts the resolution problem.

Comment: Yes, you were right... That fixes it! Is there any bug report about that?

Comment: @lepe yes this is a known problem, just don't ask me where I buried the link in my bookmarks :)

Comment: thanks. You gave me an idea and I found some links I will add to my original question.

Answer (score 2):

**Mac Keyboard User**

I had the same issue trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on virtual machine in VirtualBox 5.0.22 installed on my macbook pro 13 mid 2013.

I was not able to emulate the <kbd>right ctrl</kbd> with my keyboard therefore I opted for Luis Alvarado and Whaaaat's [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/542392/428750): in the VM Settings (under the System tab), activate the **Enable EFI checkbox** having care of selecting **PIIX3** chipset as a option.

When the installation process was completed, I disabled the EFI option and It worked like a charm.