# Zoomed in display in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, display

I'm trying to run an Ubuntu 16.04 VM in an oracle virtualbox but when I boot Ubuntu the display is extremely zoomed in. [It is so zoomed in that all of the pixels are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WofO.png) (the picture depicts the full screen view). Virtualbox display settings only give the option to zoom in further so I'm not sure what to do! Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: i think its a 3d acceleration problem. install guest-additions for virtual box.*edit too late*

Comment: posible dublicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/769589/16-04-live-cd-screen-resolution-problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set your virtualbox to **full screen** ?  it may helps .. but if not you may try setting it up to suit your screen go to **system settings** >> **Displays** >> **Resolution** you'll find many options on the list pick the suitable for you