# Trouble installing lubuntu desktop (17.04) on VM VirtualBox

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, lubuntu

(**NOTE**) I do not think this is a problem with VM VirtualBox, Previously I have installed Ubuntu server 17.04 and Ubuntu desktop 17.04 on it (both 32-bit). Ubuntu desktop was slow and unstable (random crashes) so I that is why I am trying to install Lubuntu 17.04 desktop 32-bit.

I am trying to install from an .iso file, I am able to get the menu where it says:

```
Try Lubuntu without installing
install Lubuntu
Test memory
Check disc for defects (BTW have done this, no defects found)
etc
```

I click install lubuntu. 
Then before I can do anything a black screen appears and then boom, this weird distorted screen appears. (This happened when installing Ubuntu 17.04 as well, but I was able use try Ubuntu without installing to get past this).

The problem is I get the same blue screen distortion when I try "Try Lubuntu without installing". So There is no way I can install Lubuntu.

Also note, when I press keys I see weird white lines show up, which I think are characters, so I think it may be a display problem?

I have allocated 1024 MB ram, 48 MB video memory 8 GB.vdi. Here an image of the distorted screen [image]

Comment: For any users with this problem in the future (and if the accepted solution mentioned here doesn't work): https://askubuntu.com/questions/541006/ubuntu-14-10-does-not-install-in-virtualbox. Not sure if this counts as a duplicate though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 loads Rainbow on Oracle VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812392/ubuntu-16-04-loads-rainbow-on-oracle-virtualbox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the Virtualbox site [there is an argument](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13615) about whether this is an Ubuntu or virtualbox problem.  However there is a simple workaround.

When you see the garbled screen

- hit Right Ctrl+F1 (to switch to a console display).
- switch back to the graphical display, with Right Ctrl+F7.

This should clean up your display.

Comment: thank this seems to work ctrl + f1 is graphical display for, and ctrl + f7 for console. Also I had to press it multiple times and it seems to work when keyboard capture is turned off. But I would reccomend installing lubuntu 14.04.5 since it is smaller and lighter than 17.04

Comment: (+1) perfect answer - thank you - also is 17.04 a LTS distro? Should I rather go for 16 or 18 as they have LTS versions?

Comment: @whytheq 17.04 is NOT lts and may already be end of life.  I suggest 18.04 as it's brand new and has a long life ahead of it.

Comment: Yeah.. that one has the same garbled screen

Answer (score 1):

Just after language choice, 
F6 nomodeset.

It works for me.