# Ubuntu 18 Virtual Box Glitchy Load Up

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, virtualbox, xubuntu

I am having an issue with U:18 and virtual box every time I try to start it up it will show the loading screen then stop and start flashing and won't do anything after that.

We build it through ansible so not sure if we are missing a driver or script for it.

I know it is a graphics issue since I can log into the machine when I do `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`
 and see the files in the build

[image: This is were the build stops.]

Comment: Is this the same problem you are having: https://askubuntu.com/questions/948458/trouble-installing-lubuntu-desktop-17-04-on-vm-virtualbox/948497#948497 ?

Comment: Not at all when I switch I just get the hostname and login prompt.