# Lubuntu as VBox Guest - Bad display

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, display, guest-os

I am trying out lubuntu desktop 16.10 on Virtualbox and following the "Try Lubuntu without installing" option and the VM boots but when it loads, the display is garbled and not usable:
[image]

Maximizing, changing display size does not help. I'm using the default display settings. I tried increasing ram but still no effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was able to get this to work by Enabling EFI as per https://askubuntu.com/a/542835/242975.

The Right_Ctrl+F1, Right_Ctrl+F7 did not do anything.

Comment: This also fixed issues booting BackBox Linux under Virtualbox